# Specify TimeZone for every single request

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core

My asp core 2.0 web api application stores `DateTime` in UTC format. I have user `TimeZone` information available in every request through user preference settings (stored in cookies).

The problem is that I need to return to user `DateTime` in his `TimeZone` instead of `UTC`. Do we have some build in utilities to do so?

Currently I follow the next flow:

1. User sends request with his preferences -> I retrieve his `TimeZone`
2. Process whatever request logic
3. In `OnActionExecuting` filter convert all response date time to appropriate `TimeZone`.

This approach seems to be very clumsy. I hope there is a better way to address such kind of issues. Please, suggest

Comment: I would recommend the server stick with UTC for dates/times in *most* cases (see also [Storing UTC is not a Silver Bullet - Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/). Let the client handle conversion to/from utc. Again, there will be outliers where it is better to persist the local datetime with timezone (see previous link).

Comment: Highly opinionated question, but for me I tend to think about dates and times as part of the data model.  As such, any global-level manipulation (including the one you described) would be a no-go for me.  After all, depending on what I'm doing, I may want different parts of my model to use different time zones even for the same user.